# Calling shell_exec() without waiting for the output PHP

Tags: php, linux, centos

**I Want To Call shell_exec() Without Waiting For The Output**

I Want to Execute Another php/or bash script on the background without affect the current page 
I've Tested Those:

```
'alert' > k& 
> /dev/null &
& disown
```

> And I Tested Many Others That posted here but still same thing

My Php/Bash script will execute a command to another server and it will take a while .

Comment: Putting `&` at the end should do it. Show your PHP code.

Comment: I tested them both , my php codes are too long can someone help me through Teamviewr i will appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

try this:
exec('nohup '.$command.' > ' . $outfile . ' 2>&1 & echo $!');

Comment: I tested this also , same thing i guess there is something wrong with other files that  i want to run it on background , please if anyone can connect to my PC through Teamviewer and help me i will appreciate it!